# deployment of mahout on Google app engine

Tags: google-app-engine, hadoop, cloud, mahout

Is it possible to deploy the apache mahout recommendation algorithm with their csv,txt or xml files on Google app engine.?

If really possible then how can we deploy..?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are just referring to the non-distributed, non-Hadoop part -- yes. I don't know of anything about that code that would not run on App Engine. The Hadoop-based parts probably don't work on App Engine.